# How search specific data in the page from Search input and select all that searched data of checkbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

As I descripted in the title of the subject. I would like to help me about how search specific data from Search input (for example telephone numbers: 252633000000, 252633000001) and after i clicked SELECT ALL button, I want to select only all checkboxs of the searched telephone numbers. how can i do that?

HTML

```
<input type="search" name="" id="allNumbers"/>

<button id="SearchingNumbers_btn">Select all</button>




<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000000</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000000" data-u-mobile="252633000000"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000000">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>


<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000001</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000001" data-u-mobile="252633000001"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000001">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>


<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000002</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000002" data-u-mobile="252633000002"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000002">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>
```

CSS

```
/* The container */
.container22 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container22 input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 55px;
  /*height: 25px;
  width: 25px;*/
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container22:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #f0d128;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container22 input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #C61D1D;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container22 input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container22 .checkmark:after {
    left: 24px;
    top: 36px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 27px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let container22  = document.getElementsByClassName('container22');
let container22_Length = container22.length;

let SearchingNumbers_btn = document.getElementById('SearchingNumbers_btn');
let allNumbers = document.getElementById('allNumbers');




SearchingNumbers_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var insideTextarea = allNumbers.value;
    const myArr = insideTextarea.split("\n");
    console.log(myArr);

    ...........................
    ...........................
    ...........................

});
```

Comment: You can take further help from this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/69144542/16846346 . Some starting point is provided in below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add function like in below snippet which will match any number in the telephone and if one of the number matched it will `check` the `input`

> Below snippet is for demo only on how to start you can add further functionalities when no search is found or if empty and much more according to need

[You can take some further help from here which is similar but with text search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69144542/16846346)

### Core part is

```
function refree() {
  var reader = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox_inputs")
  for (let i = 0; i < reader.length; i++) {
    var readerText = reader[i].value
    var reed = document.getElementById("allNumbers").value;
    if (reed != '') {
      if (readerText.indexOf(reed) > -1) {
        reader[i].checked = true;
      }
    } else {
      reader[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

### Let's see how this works

When search btn is clicked

1. it will take run a function `refree`(can name any)
2. all `input` are called with a variable `reader` which we will use to take values from each `input`
3. `for` loop is applied which work as a checker for each input , the loop is running number of `input`(telephone number) times (here 3) .
4. value from `input` is taken into `readerText` variable and `search` value is taken into `reed` variable . (variable can be named any)
5. Now a condition is run `if` `search` is not empty than it is `true` and 1st statement will run else the second one
6. When statement is `true` than again a condition is passed which check whether searched number is present or not (**Here single number is matched than also input will be checked which can be changed to only check when complete number is matched**) .

> Main work here is of [`.indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) which is searching search query inside all numbers

> If you want complete number to be matched than change condition
> `readerText.indexOf(reed) > -1` to `readerText=== reed`

```js
let container22 = document.getElementsByClassName('container22');
let container22_Length = container22.length;

let SearchingNumbers_btn = document.getElementById('SearchingNumbers_btn');
let allNumbers = document.getElementById('allNumbers');



SearchingNumbers_btn.addEventListener("click", refree);

function refree() {
  var reader = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox_inputs")
  for (let i = 0; i < reader.length; i++) {
    var readerText = reader[i].value
    var reed = document.getElementById("allNumbers").value;
    if (reed != '') {
      if (readerText.indexOf(reed) > -1) {
        reader[i].checked = true;
      } else {
        reader[i].checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      reader[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* The container */

.container22 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container22 input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 55px;
  /*height: 25px;
  width: 25px;*/
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container22:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #f0d128;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container22 input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #C61D1D;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container22 input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
  top: 7px;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container22 .checkmark:after {
  left: 24px;
  top: 36px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 27px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="allNumbers" />

<button id="SearchingNumbers_btn">Select all</button>




<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000000</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000000" data-u-mobile="252633000000"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000000">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>


<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000001</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000001" data-u-mobile="252633000001"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000001">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>


<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000002</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000002" data-u-mobile="252633000002"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000002">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

### Update

Now the complete multiple numbers will be searched with a space in between

> The `for` inside the function
>
> > for each one of your checkboxes you set the `checked` value if the `allNumbers` list includes the expected value. `false` otherwise.

```js
let container22 = document.getElementsByClassName('container22');
let container22_Length = container22.length;

let SearchingNumbers_btn = document.getElementById('SearchingNumbers_btn');
let allNumbers = document.getElementById('allNumbers');



SearchingNumbers_btn.addEventListener("click", refree);

function refree() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox_inputs");
  var allNumbers = document.getElementById("allNumbers").value.trim().split(" ");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = allNumbers
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].checked = allNumbers.includes(inputs[i].value);
  }
}
```

```css
/* The container */

.container22 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container22 input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 55px;
  /*height: 25px;
  width: 25px;*/
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container22:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #f0d128;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container22 input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #C61D1D;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container22 input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
  top: 7px;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container22 .checkmark:after {
  left: 24px;
  top: 36px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 27px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="allNumbers" />

<button id="SearchingNumbers_btn">Select all</button>




<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000008</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000008" data-u-mobile="252633000008"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000008">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>


<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000001</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000001" data-u-mobile="252633000001"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000001">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>


<label class="container22" style="background-color: #96e676;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div>252633000007</div>
        <input class="checkbox_inputs" type="checkbox" name="sending" class="Sending_JS" value="252633000007" data-u-mobile="252633000007"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="252633000007">

        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</label>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i want (for example if i search two numbers like 252633000000,252633000001 and more) i want to checked these two numbers in html not only one phone number every time, i want to check mutliple result, how can i do that?

Comment: then you can use a certain separator that may be ` ` (space), `,` (comma),  `;`(don't know name) . And split the values on these separators which are then entered into an array which will search for telephone number and if found will `check` all the matched input separately `input`

Comment: Rana, could you explain in code above please, i tried that but it is not working?

Comment: Perfect the code is working, thank you very much Rana

Comment: No problem , if answer has helped you , you can mark it as accepted and can also upvote